# Designing action Bar in android or make it alone

Tags: android, android-layout

how to make the bar in the top of the picture (see the link) (drawerbutton,"mes cercles",picture_pen)? by customizing the action bar or i make it manually?

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6Cz2zvfARSdOHJKSEppSzd6ZHM&usp=sharing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11950289/2219600

Answer (score 0):

The ActionBar in that screenshot is custom-made. It is not built using Android's ActionBar controls. It appears that it was created using a RelativeLayout with a custom background, 1 button on each side and text in the middle of the layout. You can do this as well, however, it is considered best-practice to use Android's ActionBar, which can be themed partially. (Background, text color, buttons, logo, etc...)

Since Android's ActionBar is relatively new, you should use ActionBarSherlock, which adds compatibility to Android 2.x.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the actionbar in android to a very good extent , give it a solid / gradient background , customize the font face , add buttons , event give to different round corner values, also tabs are available ,  i suggest that method so you don't need plug-ins

the below two posts might be useful

[android developers page  /  actionbar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

[Using the Android action bar (ActionBar) - Tutorial - Vogella](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CFQQFjAF&url=http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html&ei=YKnaUt-jOsWShQfC9oC4CQ&usg=AFQjCNF14Bn0qGyr0NQARAARdPfAbpcWSw&sig2=tusdiw-_GSrLoF794oKOqQ&bvm=bv.59568121,d.ZG4)